# Regarding bigtable row transactions

Tags: transactions, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I would like to understand how BigTable row level transactions work for the following scenario?

Lets say row has the key 'k' and the value as set of elements {E1, E2}

case a) Request A read the row with key 'k' and appends the value E3 to the current set {E1, E2, E3}

case b) Read B read the row with key 'k' and appends the value E4 to the current set {E1, E2, E4}

What we want eventually is {{E1, E2, E3, E4}

Q1) Does one of the requests mentioned in the case a or case b fail if both of the requests trying to update the row at the same time because of the row level transaction ?

Q2) If there is a delay between the append operations, is there a good chance that the preceeding update will be overwritten with the subsequent update right ?

Q3) If the above is yes, we are considering conditional write to achieve what we want. For example for case b) we will use pre-condition (CheckAndMutateRow) for the value as {E1, E2}. However our value is a bitset represented in byte value that could have size in kbs and concerned about performance with such sizes. I understand that we could store the timestamp with each cell while updating the value for that cell and wondering if we could use the timestamp of the cell value as the pre-condition? If not, we can maintain the explicit updated_ts as the separate cell.

Q4) Could we use batch conditional write as the example (https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples/bigtable-writes-conditional) and lib doesn't seem to support bach conditional write

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the answers to everything right now but here is some info that might help you get started.

Appends and increments are atomic operations that are applied in order. If both operations are sent at the same time it is possible to get {E1,E2,E3,E4} as a result but also {E1,E2,E4,E3}, but I don't think it would fail, it would probably just apply them in some order.

If you add a delay between operations, the second would be appended afterwards – yes, but there wouldn't be any overwriting it would just append the bytes to the existing cell value.